# MVC2 IIS - Properly resolve URLs in external style sheets and scripts upon deployment?

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc-2, iis

I changed my Visual Studio MVC2 project to debug on a local IIS server, but I ran into problems with how the URLs are resolved.

Instead of hard-coding the links for say an ajax request, I now have to use the ResolveUrl() method like so:

```
<%= ResolveUrl("~/Controller/Action")%>
```

Which is fine when the javascript lives in a view.  But I have javascript in external .js files which I can't use the ResolveUrl() function inside of.

This problem also affects links to images within external style sheets.

I feel like I shouldn't need to manually change these links every time I move from the Visual Studio web server to a local IIS web server, to an actual deployed web server.

What is the best way to work around this?

So far all I can think of is using a relative path such as ../Content/Images/image.gif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few tips I can give you. First of all you should not use `ResolveUrl` for resolving controller actions because you are still hardcoding and not taking advantage of the routes. What if tomorrow you decide to change your route definitions in global.asax? You should use Url helpers like this:

```
<%= Url.Action("Action", "Controller") %>
```

and for static resources:

```
<%= Url.Content("~/scripts/foo.js") %>
```

Now when you need to define image paths in CSS files you should know that they could be relative to the location of the CSS file. So for example if you include your CSS like this:

```
<link href="<%= Url.Content("~/styles/foo.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

inside `foo.css` you could use relative image paths:

```
.foo {
    /** you can safely define relative image paths in relation with the CSS **/
    background-image: url(../images/foo.png);
}
```

and the last part are javascript files. Inside them you cannot use helpers to define urls. So different techniques exist. Personally I like unobtrusive javascript with progressive enhancement meaning that the url I need is already in the HTML. Think for example AJAXifying a link or a form. Inside your view you would have:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("foo bar", "foo") %>
```

and inside a separate javascript we could AJAXify it:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $('result').load(this.href);
    return false;
});
```

There are case though where you do not have the url in the DOM. So you could use a global variable inside the view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myurl = '<%= Url.Action("foo") %>';
</script>
```

and inside your external javascript use this `myurl` global variable.

Comment: having global variables... aH!!! that just sucks man.. I would hv probably negative voted if nt for mentioning the different ways of hadnling various cases.

Comment: I ended up doing the global javascript variable as suggested here, I put them in my site.master head area.  Thank you both for the tips on the Url.Content() and other advice!

Answer (score 1):

So what I would suggest is in your c# file you have an hidden text field and you write the absolute url path there and you append your path to the external js file after reading from the text file.

But I really dont see any gains out of loading another js file from a js file. Just load all the files at once and us eit conditionally within yoiur js file. I am assuming that you are loading the other js file from the js file itself cos you want to perform some action on loading the js file. you can achieve the same by just calling the function in the next file on window.load of the first file.. is that what your ultimate goal is?

I dont think you understood what I was getting into.

Say you have to do a postback to do a controller Food and action GetMenu then in your aspx page you will have a hidden field with the value set as follows:

```
<input type="hidden" id="hidden-getmenu-locator" value=<%=Url.Action("GetMenu","Food") %> />
```

and regarding your css and js you can get them as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.custom.min.js")%>"></script>
```

or again store in a hidden field and then use it.

Hope that helps

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are getting at.  I have javascript objects in external .js files that are loaded on the page as needed.  Some of them use ajax to post back to the server, which is where the problem with the hard-coded URL is.  Similar situation for my external CSS.  I use CSS sprites and the background-image URL is hard-coded in those as well.

Comment: I see what you are getting at now, but I don't believe it is relevant.  Maybe I didn't explain my question well enough :(  I don't have a problem importing the external .css and .js files.  The problem is, inside of those files I have hard-coded paths that I can't use something like ResolveURL(), ot Url.Action() on.  Unless there is a way to use those functions inside of external .css and .js files?  I assumed there was not.  The external .css and .js files are still local to the server, but I believe asp.net treats them as static content.

Comment: Ran out of comment space.  I'd rather not have to have hidden inputs on my site.master to allow my external javascript to get the correct path.  That is do-able, however it does not address the css issue.

Comment: I really dont get it.. why cant you do something like this in your JS:

var urlForAjaxCall=$('#hidden-getmenu-locator').val(); 
and now use the above stored url in your ajax call..

Comment: regarding css.. relative is the wat u handle stuff.. so if ur css is located under certain folder you use ../ etc get to the root folder and then get into the image folder